# Parsing a YAML file

Tags: yaml

I've tried 5 or 6 online YAML parsers and they all give me the same error- groups:

```
ERROR:

mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<unicode string>", line 3, column 12:
        default: true
               ^
```

I've also researched the spacing, and it appears to be correct. The "default" is 4 spaces away from the edge and "true" is one space away from the colon.

This is the complete file I'm trying to edit

```
groups:
  Member
    default: true
    build: true
    prefix: '&b&lMember&f'
    permissions:
    - shop.use
    - shop.destroy


  Donator
    build: true
    inheritance: Member
    - Default
    prefix: '&d&lDonator&f'
    permissions:
    - 
    -
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (are?) the block headings `Member` and `Donator`, etc. *before* `default: true` and `build: true`.

Multiple nesting in YAML requires that the preceding key have a colon *after* it. Without this, it would appear YAML parsers will simply think that the key ends at the next line (i.e. at `default`, so that the key is `Member\n   default`) which is a no-no and triggers correctly the error you see.

Simply change this to

```
groups:
 Member: # note the colon here!
    default: true
    build: true
    prefix: '&b&lMember&f'
    permissions:
        - shop.use
        - shop.destroy
```

etc.

In Python with PyYAML, the above snippet is translated to

```
>>> yaml.safe_load(open("testfile.yaml")
{'groups': {'Members': {'default': True, 'prefix': '&b&lMember&f', 'build': True, 'permissions': ['shop.use', 'shop.destroy']}}}
```

---

The remainder of your YAML is not valid either. Do something about the weird `- DEFAULT` in the middle of your nesting, or else your YAML will fail to be parsed, as `inheritance: Member` will effectively end the block.

Comment: Thank you so much; the -Default should be -Member, I wasn't focused on that because I was just trying to get the format right first